# Should a www. to m. redirect for mobile devices accessing a PC site use a 301 or a 302?

Tags: mobile, redirect, seo

I read in a few places that people are recommending a 301 redirect to redirect mobile devices from a PC site the mobile optimised site.

- Making Websites Mobile Friendly (Google Webmaster blog) - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html
- Untangling Your Mobile Metrics With Better Redirects - http://searchengineland.com/untangling-your-mobile-metrics-with-better-redirects-113015?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=feed-main

The arguments seem to be 1) Reduce duplication in Google search results and 2) Preserve referrer.

However the side affect of doing a permanent redirect is that you couldn't give the option of the user back to the PC version if they wanted (since the 301 permanent redirect would have been cached by the client) - See http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/a-very-modern-mobile-switching-algorithm-part-ii for why giving user choice is important.

What is the recommendation to optimise for search (e.g. following Google's SEO guidelines) at the same time as giving the user choice as to whether to visit the mobile or PC site?

Comment: how about displaying a link "for PC version click here" which would have a query string like "?force-pc=true" and check for this value before the 301 redirect; then set a cookie and check for the cookie before the redirect as well

Comment: We had Cache-Control:private for our 301s so this parameter wasn't having any effect.  Switching this to Cache-Control:no-cache makes the 301 not cached and so the check happens on each request.  So perhaps the advice is to use a 301 redirect with "Cache-Control" header set to "no-cache".

Answer (score 0):

If you craft your regex carefully, you could probably make redirection happen only for URLs that don't have the "force" parameter. After all, you probably want fine-grained control over that redirection anyway, rather than have blanket rules, so that you can control one-to-one page mapping.

Answer (score 0):

[Google now says it doesn't matter](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects), as long as you do your canonical tags properly:

> HTTP redirection is a commonly used to redirect clients to
>   device-specific URLs. Usually, the redirection is done based on the
>   user-agent in the HTTP request headers. It is important to keep the
>   redirection consistent with the alternate URL specified in the page's
>   link rel="alternate" tag or in the Sitemap.
>
> For this purpose, **it does not matter if the server redirects with an
>   HTTP 301 or a 302 status code**.